# How to create a new column calculating price changes without using lagged values?

Tags: r, zoo

Everyone. Thank you for taking your time to view my question. I appreciate it.

So I am having trouble with lagged values in R, for example - I have the below table:

```
Semiannual    Price    Start    End    Multiplier   
  2010 Q1      121      .04     .06         1
  2010 Q2      121      .065    .059       1.083
  2011 Q1      121      .061    .063       1.0338
  2011 Q2      121      .057    .087       0.904
```

The above is a sample stock data I have for some portfolio ABC. Essentially, I have the price of the portfolio at t-0 (which is 121) and the Start column is the opening price on the start of the semi-annual period, and the end column is closing price in the semiannual period. I do rebalacing at the end of each semi-annual period, hence, I need to keep the Price (or my base) consistent throughout, and It requires me to multiply the Price (121) by the percent change in the opening price of the new period / closing price of the ending period. So Ideally, My results would be:

```
Semiannual    Price    Start    End    Multiplier   Actual Price
  2010 Q1      121      .04     .06         1         121
  2010 Q2      121      .065    .059       1.083      131.043
  2011 Q1      121      .061    .063       1.0338     135.4723
  2011 Q2      121      .057    .087       0.904      122.4669
```

But I cannot for the life of me get the code for multiplying the lagged value of Actual Price by the multiplier since the column isn't defined when I start the calculations.

I hope I am making some sense...

Essentially taking the lagged value of the actual price * Multiplier for each quarter, but quarter 1 is just itself (121).

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to look at previous rows...
The multiplier can be calculated using `cumprod()`, which i call temp_multiplier .. after that, the price calculation is easy.. delete the temporary multiplier afterwards.

```
df <- read.table(text="Semiannual    Price    Start    End    Multiplier   
2010-Q1      121      .04     .06         1
2010-Q2      121      .065    .059       1.083
2011-Q1      121      .061    .063       1.0338
2011-Q2      121      .057    .087       0.904", header = T)

library( tidyverse )

df %>% mutate ( temp_Multiplier = cumprod( Multiplier ),
                Actual_price = temp_Multiplier * Price ) %>%
  select ( -temp_Multiplier )

#   Semiannual Price Start   End Multiplier Actual_price
# 1    2010-Q1   121 0.040 0.060     1.0000     121.0000
# 2    2010-Q2   121 0.065 0.059     1.0830     131.0430
# 3    2011-Q1   121 0.061 0.063     1.0338     135.4723
# 4    2011-Q2   121 0.057 0.087     0.9040     122.4669
```